# __strong qualifier used in non ARC project

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

The project is non-ARC enabled, however we are (mistakingly) using ARC compliant code libraries - specifically one to create singleton objects like so defined in GCDSingleton.h:

```
#define DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
  static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
  __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    _sharedObject = ^{return [[self alloc] init];}();
  });
  return _sharedObject;
}
```

This seems to work even though the shared object is defined with an __strong qualifier. I'm wondering why this doesn't cause an error or at least a warning (latest Xcode 4.6 and ios 6 sdk). Also, since the project is not ARC enabled, what exactly is that __strong qualifier doing, if anything?

Answer (score 5):

In MRC code, `__strong` is simply ignored.

I tried to compile a simple example

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    __strong NSString * foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %s", argv[1]];
    NSLog(@"%@", foo);
}
```

with ARC

```
clang -fobjc-arc test.m -S -emit-llvm -o arc.ir
```

and without ARC

```
clang -fno-objc-arc test.m -S -emit-llvm -o mrc.ir
```

and to diff the llvm IR output.

Here's the result of `diff mrc.ir arc.ir`

```
54a55,56
>   %17 = bitcast %0** %foo to i8**
>   call void @objc_storeStrong(i8** %17, i8* null) nounwind
63a66,67
> declare void @objc_storeStrong(i8**, i8*)
>
```

So basically the only difference between ARC and MRC is the addition of a `objc_storeStrong` call.

---

By the way the same code without the `__strong` qualifier will produce the same exact results, since `__strong` is the default qualifier for variables in ARC.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought as well - otherwise I would expect at least a compile error or segfaults due to deallocated objects.

Comment: why? You are assigning (in a funny way - why define a thunk and call it?) an object with a +1 retain count to a static variable that will never go out of scope. No crash, as expected.

Comment: You misunderstood. I meant if it weren't working as expected, then something is causing it to be deallocated, which is not happening. Anyway, no issue here.